# Android Layout -- View on the left and View centered in Parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Sorry if this question has been asked before, but I haven't seen anything on Google/SO, and frustratingly everything I've tried in coded hasn't worked.

What I'm trying to accomplish is have a menu ImageButton aligned on the left-side and have a logo ImageView centered on screen.  However, if the logo image is too large it overlaps the menu button, so I added layout_toRightOf.  Unfortunately, the logo is no longer centered.

I've also tried to use a LinearLayout but no luck.

Here's the current layout I have:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:rounded="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rootView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Title Bar -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/menuButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/menu_item_lite"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/menuButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menuButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />
<RelativeLayout/>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to make sure that the imageView is always centered on the screen, as well as always to the right of the menuButton, you could go with a (slightly hacky) approach of adding another invisible menu button on the right side of the screen, and having the center image be left of that as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:rounded="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Title Bar -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/menuButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_item_lite"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/menuButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menuButton"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/invisibleMenuButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/invisibleMenuButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_item_lite"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it the other way around, center the logo and use toLeftOf in the imagebutton

Comment: i tried this too; however, the imageButton moved off the left side to a more centered position between the left edge the logo

Comment: if you want to also keep it to the border, you can use both toLeftOf and alignParentLeft

Comment: have that in there too "android:layout_alignParentLeft="true""

Answer (score 0):

you can change the order of the images so that menu image will always be above logo:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:rounded="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rootView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Title Bar -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/menuButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menuButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />    
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/menuButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/menu_item_lite"/>


<RelativeLayout/>
```